# Optimal choosing : MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, statistics

Consider 2 sets

```
A = randi(1000,100,7);
B = randi(700,300,7);
```

I would like to find a function : `B# = optimf(A,B)` and gives me `B# = {100x7}` which is a collection of rows from `B` such that some attribute( eg. mean ) is minimum.

For eg: `B# = optimf(A,B)` such that `mean(B#) - mean(A)` is minimum.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define `mean`: along rows? Along columns? Both?

Comment: Column-wise mean or mean of each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to me Optimization is finding the best suitable value of a function. For example, if you have an equation and you need to find minimum value at which the equation satisfies criteria, then this is an optimization problem.

There is no such optimization function AFAIK for your function. But, you can take help of optimization algorithms like [Least Square Errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)

Or simply use some filter of MATLAB.

I hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

(Not a sophisticated solution but just works in some cases.)

**Step 1-**

Make a for-loop and select randomly some values from input vector. So you get a random subset.

**Step 2**

Define a cost function. A function that can measure how good is the subset. The function will take input as vector and gives output a numerical quantity such as % of quality.

**Step 3**

Go on taking these readings. Take the max value of output function and its corresponding vector. That should be a solution.

OR

use algorithms like [ACO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms)

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something more in the lines of an optimal mapping. The best selection of an input vector for the desired output. 

I don't have any idea about the filters. How( and which ones) would help this case?

Comment: So, I guess you are looking for a subset of input vector that fits some criteria right?